# Our research aimed at defining criteria based on which we CAN (or COULD?) differentiate patients from normal subjects

Tags: modal-verbs, grammaticality-in-context

In this excerpt from a twitter feed:

> New insights into the testing of schizophrenia. Our research aimed at defining quantitative criteria based on which we **can** differentiate schizophrenic spectrum disorders from the norm.

I think that the modal verb **could** should be used instead of **can**, because the main clause is framed in the past tense. Furthermore, the criteria were not known beforehand, which makes **can** less appropriate in my view.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between **can** and **could** in this context is whether you actually do what you say.

> The ceiling is so low that I can touch it!
>   The ceiling is so low that I could touch it.

In the first sentence the speaker is demonstrating as they speak that they are able to touch the ceiling, whereas in the second sentence the speaker is describing a possibility without actually doing it.

> Our research aimed at defining quantitative criteria based on which we can differentiate schizophrenic spectrum disorders from the norm.

In this sentence, the speaker is talking about the past objective of past (and possibly continuing) research.The use of the word **can** indicates that, if the research was/is successful, the criteria has been/will be used to identify schizophrenia.

If **could** were used instead, it would suggest one of these possibilities- maybe others too

- the research was completed but failed to identify suitable criteria
- that the research was successful but nobody wanted to use it
- that it was never an objective to use the criteria even if they were identified

Comment: Very interesting. I thought that **could** would be perfectly okay there. Now it turns out that the only proper verb to use is **can**. I thought it had to do with the general tense framework of the main clause. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's correct (it's ***not*** true that "the only proper verb to use is ***can***"). In fact, arguably ***could*** is somewhat *more* natural / accurate for the exact context, given it's hard to argue that ***can/could*** means anything other than ***is / will / would be able to***. And *...criteria based on which we **are able to** differentiate...* doesn't look good to me as an alternative here, since we're talking about a hypothetical future .situation, not something we're currently doing (because we haven't yet found out ***how*** to do it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, I agree that **could** is perfectly possible, but I don't think that it is more natural, even somewhat more natural. Remember that this sentence is talking about the statement of objectives, not what is likely to be achieved. I therefore maintain that **can** implies an intent to use, where as **could** implies a theoretical possibility ot use.

Comment: I have no particular preference between ***can / could*** for the cited context, and I'm far from convinced the choice woulds normally reflect any real-world difference. It could make a difference whether the *results* of the (past) research are known ***at all*** at time of utterance (which the OP doesn't specify), AND (if known) whether those results do indeed facilitate the desired differentiation (or perhaps are now known ***not*** to work). With the info we have so far, you could even defend ***we would have been able to differentiate...*** (but actually ***we failed*** in that goal).